# Untangle Facebook reaction encoding?

Tags: python, facebook, unicode, emoji

I've downloaded my Facebook data in JSON format and want to perform analysis on it. It contains segments like:

```
{
          "reaction": "\u00e2\u009d\u00a4",
          "actor": "..."
},
```

The reaction here is a heart. However, if I print it in Python, obviously it comes out as simply those unicode characters (â¤), rather than a heart.

Does anyone know if there's somewhere that contains all of Facebook's reaction encodings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heart emoji character is encoded in Unicode as U+2764. In UTF-8 encoding form, that character would be represented as a sequence of three bytes, `0xE2 0x9D 0xA4`.

Facebook is mixing up UTF-8 encoding form versus the Unicode code point. Since it is escaping the character using `\uxxxx` format, it should present that as `\u2764`. But instead, in formatting the escaped sequence, it is (incorrectly) taking the UTF-8 byte sequence and re-interpreting each byte as though it were a complete character.

(Unfortunately, there are still too many products that make similar errors in handling UTF-8 encoded strings. E.g., I've seen this in my car when music track details from a streaming service are displayed. Whenever you see garbage sequences of two, three or four characters from the Unicode [Latin-1 Supplement block](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf), that's what's going on.)

You can find info about Facebook's reactions and the (nearest) corresponding Unicode emoji character at https://emojipedia.org/facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook is erroneously writing the JSON. You can fix the reaction by encoding the string to bytes using `latin1` encoding, then correctly decoding as `utf8`:

```
reaction = "\u00e2\u009d\u00a4".encode('latin1').decode()
print(reaction)  # ❤
```